# How to create a field type based on another field value?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write types for the following simplified example.
How can I tell `Container` that the config will be derived from the `component`?

```js
type Container = {
  component: "A" | "B" | "C";
  config: AConfig | BConfig | CConfig;
}

type App = {
  containers: Container[];
}
```

I tried using generics, but then the `containers` in `App` cannot have multiple types.

```js
type Config = {
  A: AConfig;
  B: BConfig;
  C: CConfig;
}

type Container<T extends keyof Config> = {
  component: T;
  config: Config[T];
}

type App<T> = {
  containers: Container<T>[];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a mapped type to iterate over the keys of your `Config` type and create the pairing.

```
type ConfigContainer = {
    [K in keyof Config]: { component: K, config: Config[K] }
}[keyof Config]
```

This creates an object type that has all possible pairings as values, and then you index that object by it's own keys to get the value types as a union.

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAggwgewHYDMCWBzKBeKBvKAQwC4oBnYAJzSSwF8AoUSKAIUVUx3ygCNSK1WlEbNocDuiy4CAYwFUa9Bk3DjkU7ngZRYpeBswBuHW1LtDGE7rikJlk41UsOwQjQiUAPABUoEAA9gCCQAEzIoAGsIEAQUKElMAD4tU1kEAFswZBDgUh9rKHTODDtLAG0fAF1HFTEEy1d3JE9U3V1ygGkoGiiYuIaSqtI5TOyWpDyoToAaIssykq6qkQY6cujY+MSMKrq1WDAwNvnJ5s8yRakmj0pymrWGYooiI4BxBARQ-SOtU7dbpcoOVRlkcpNSAAiGCQubFKQjIhQwi8WSQkQiFaMZ7AV5gViEb6HY4yf7nShAkHzMETKbQ2GnBE8fhQSG8QnouiYjEAeh5-kolAQlCAA)

Comment: Can't I use the `Config` and create the `Container` accordingly?
Something like `entries(Config).map(({k, v}) => ({component: k, config: v}))`

Comment: See my updated answer